# Harmonic majoration proof. Why does domain need to be relatively compact?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

I am having trouble understanding why $D$ needs to be relatively compact (compact closure) in the following theorem:

> **Theorem** Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $u: \, U \to [-\infty, \infty)$ be a subharmonic function. Further, let $D$ be a relatively compact subdomain of $U$, and $h$ be a harmonic functions on $D$ such that \begin{eqnarray} \limsup_{z \to \zeta} (u-h)(z) \leq 0  \quad (\zeta \in \partial D),\end{eqnarray} then $u \leq h$ on $D$.
>
> *Proof.* The function $u-h$ is subharmonic on $D$, so the result follow by the maximum principle.

This is the theorem being used:

> **Maximum Principle** Let $u$ be subharmonic on a domain in $\mathbb{C}$. If $\limsup_{z \to \zeta}u(z) \leq 0$ for all $\zeta \in \partial D$, then $u \leq 0$ on $D$.

So the proof makes perfect sense, except for why it isn't enough for $D$ to just be a domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compactness assumption on $D$ is natural because the maximum principle for harmonic functions can fail in unbounded domains. For example, let $U=\mathbb C,$ and $D=\{x+iy: y>0\}.$ Define $u\equiv 0,$ $h(x+iy)=-y.$ Then $\partial D = \mathbb R,$ and

$$\limsup_{z\to \zeta}\, (u(z)-h(z)) =0$$

for all $\zeta \in \mathbb R.$ But clearly $u-h\le 0$ fails in $D.$

Comment: But we have a convention that $\infty \in \partial D$ whenever $D$ is unbounded?

Comment: I don't see anything in the maximum principle that states that the domain needs to be bounded?

Comment: @K.Carlsen Yes, if you allow $\infty \in \partial D$ then my example doesn't work.